# Replacing <img src> via pure CSS

Tags: css

Firstly, thanks in advance, I've been trying to figure this out for hours now and I just can't work it out..

I don't have access to the backend PHP / HTML but I want to change a few images in a sites design..

How can I change these images by pure CSS alone ? Is this even possible ?

```
<a href="example.php?action=task1" class="tooltip" title="task1">
<img src="/example/1/image1.png" alt="RP"></a>

<a href="example.php?action=task2" class="tooltip" title="task2">
<img src="/example/1/image2.png" alt="RP"></a>
```

Comment: Can you clarify with more details, like where are you trying to do this? is it in your browser? What exactly do you want the outcome to be? etc

Comment: Yeah, it builds a row of icons on a website and i'm wanting to change the icons to something more modern but i only have access to the css and at a push, maybe JS too via tampermonkey..

Comment: Did you try the inspect element method in your browser's developer tools (f12) and replace the image urls that way?

Comment: Yeah I can edit them that way but I need it in the CSS ideally so it can be passed on to others..

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the `src` attribute via CSS, because the `src` attribute is an HTML attribute, outside the scope of CSS styling. But:

## background-image

If you want a pure CSS solution, then you can place `div`s instead of `img`, possibly wrapping the `div`s around the anchors.

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-image: /example/1/image1.png;"><a href="example.php?action=task1" class="tooltip" title="task1"></div>
```

See an example here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

I know you do not have access to HTML development, but if you will have access, then it's worth knowing that it can be solved this way.

## Javascript

With Javascript you can easily sun something like:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (let image of images) {
    //Do something with image.src
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a pseudo-element after the images. I know of a couple places where psuedo-elements aren't allowed (like on form elements), but on the images or the links that wrap them you could use something like the following

```css
img { position: relative; display: block; width: 350px; height: 150px;  }
img:after { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url( 'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150' )
}
```

```html
<img src="/example/1/image1.png" alt="RP">
```

The biggest thing to remember (for me at least) is the `content` attribute is required for `:before` & `:after` psuedo-elements

Comment: This looks like it can achieve what I'm trying to do though, there are 6 in total, all with their own images though so how do I tell them apart in the CSS to add a new source URL for each..

Comment: @MrWhite If you wanted to change them for each specific image you could use an attribute selector, eg: `img[src="/example/1/image1.png"]` or you could specify a specifix index using the `:nth-child()` selector to select a specific image based on it's index

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below using content applied to image and an attribute selector to identify each one:

```css
img[src*="image1.png"] {
 content:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/200/300);
}

img[src*="image2.png"] {
 content:url(https://picsum.photos/id/15/250/400);
}
```

```html
<a href="example.php?action=task1" class="tooltip" title="task1">
<img src="/example/1/image1.png" alt="RP"></a>

<a href="example.php?action=task2" class="tooltip" title="task2">
<img src="/example/1/image2.png" alt="RP"></a>
```